# Use the result of a query as a filter in another of different db in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho

I need to use the result brought from a query in MySql as a filter for another Postgre query in Pentaho.

example:

Query1:

```
 SELECT GROUP_CONCAT("'",`name`, "'" SEPARATOR ', ') as names
 FROM mysql.table;
```

Query2:

```
 SELECT * from postgre.table WHERE name in (ResultQuery1);
```

I use the table input step for the query´s but I don't know how to pass the result of the first query as a parameter for the second query.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this by **Insert data from step** in **table input** step. mention this field and place "**?**"  in query

[check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dr3WA.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass values from a previous query as parameters using a ? Placeholder for each parameter,  with a couple caveats: number of ? must match number of fields from previous step and in the same order.

In the 2nd table input choose the 1st step name in the box “insert data from step” and check “execute for every input row.

Each row of data will generate a separate SQL query, with 1 value in each one, so you may also want to replace the IN operand by =

Comment: thanks for your reply nsousa, what is the step "Placeholder for each parameter"?

Comment: It’s not a step, but a question mark in the query. On your 2nd table input type the query as “select ... where name = ?”

Comment: thanks nsousa. 
I had not understood, with the image of PKP I realized. Thank you very much for your answer